# Why use IDictionary for Child Classes for NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

As I read here
http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=NHibernate

for example

```
public class Department
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private IDictionary classes;
    private IDictionary professors;
}
```

Why not use Generic List ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are more efficient when performing that kind of lookup. Lists are great but if you're dealing with *pairs* of values (such as class ID/name, professor ID/person ID) dictionary lookups will be faster. Dictionaries also offer additional functionality, e.g. finding out if an element exists. With a list you'd have to loop through the entire thing (slower and more code) while dictionaries are indexed for you.

Hope that helps